# Appending vs. Concatenating Large Files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, cat, io-redirection

Let say I have 5 very large 100GB files.
`file1` `file2` `file3` `file4` `file5`

If I wanted to combine them into `fileAll`, is there a speed (read/write) difference between the following two ways? (Let's disregard working disk space for now)

**Cat and redirect:**

`cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 > fileAll`

**Cat, append, and move/rename:**

`cat file2 file3 file4 file5 >> file1`

`mv file1 fileAll`

**My assumtion:**

I assume `cat` will read in each file entirely that it is concatenating (in this example a total of 500GB worth of reading) and then redirect `>` will write out everything (total 500GB worth of writing).

In the second example, I am assuming that `cat` will read in one less file (total 400GB worth of reading) and then when appending `>>` simply write out that in the space after the file we are appending to (total 400GB worth of writing).

Am I correct in assuming that **appending does not have to read in the entire file being appended to and can simply start writing at the end of that file?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to scan through the file to find the end.

Comment: So would there be no speed gain? Would it then read in 500GB and write out 400GB in the example above?

Comment: Just try it with some 1 GB files?

Comment: I am still waiting for my script to finish generating the data. I will have 8 big parts in two days and wanted to know which way was better without having to test it out on my real data. That way I can hit the ground running. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. "appending" only require one "seek" call to the file end. Nothing will be read from file1 in case 2.